# jquery date parser error getting NaN error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written below function for setting date text field which is daterangepicker.js. On chrome console its throwing "gluingNaN/NaN/NaN-NaN/NaN/NaN "

Code :

```
function onloadDate(){
    var d1=new Date(Date.parse('today -30days'));
    var date1=d1.getMonth()+1 +"/"+ d1.getDate() +"/"+ d1.getFullYear();
    var d=new Date(Date.parse('today'));
    var date2=d.getMonth()+1 +"/"+ d.getDate() +"/"+ d.getFullYear();
    var dateselected1=date1+"-"+date2;
    var presetFromDate = getPresetFilters("fromDate");
    var presetToDate = getPresetFilters("toDate");
    var presetDateOption = getPresetFilters("dateOption");
    if(sessionStorage.getItem("onloadDate") == null || sessionStorage.getItem("onloadDate") == undefined || sessionStorage.getItem("onloadDate") == "")
    {
        dateOption = "DateRange";
        $('#dateRange').val(dateselected1);
        sessionStorage.setItem("onloadDate","true");
        console.log("gluing"  + dateselected1);
        applyFiltersOnLoad();

        console.log("filter data with date"+sessionStorage.getItem("filterData"));
    }
    else{
        $('#dateRange').value = dateselected1;

    }

}
```

please help me finding the bug.

Comment: What is `Date.parse('today -30days')`? I haven't seen these

Answer (score 1):

Date.parse accepts according to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse):

```
A string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date.
```

Therefore, your call `Date.parse('today -30days')` is wrong. You can use

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate()-30);
```

to subtract 30 days from `date`.

Answer (score 0):

Check

[ISO8601](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)

or

[IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14)

According to these your date-time string must be formatted according to this:

1995-02-05T00:00:00